# rxjs retry with delay and multicast

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to build an rxjs chain that ultimately calls a library function which returns a promise (that is, I can't change anything beyond that call):

```js
  libraryCall(): Promise<SomeOutput> { /* opaque to me */ }
```

Said `libraryCall` promise may resolve or reject (as any promise).

If the promise resolves, then everything must work as a plain call, nothing else added.

If the promise rejects, then it should retry (call `libraryCall` again) indefinitely (yes, indefinitely, since that promise returns a very important piece of information), after some constant time (1s for example).

The resulting observable will only emit once (after N `libraryCall`'s promises rejecting, and 1 `libraryCall`'s promise resolving).

If any new client subscribes to the resulting observable while it is looping, retrying for ever, then it should piggyback on that loop. Once a promise resolves, then all pending clients should get that resolved value.

As a last requirement, if every pending client unsubscribes, then the retry loop should be aborted.

#### What have I done so far?

```
    defer(() => libraryCall()).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000))),
      shareReplay(0),
    );
```

It is almost working. But... after resolving once, any new subscription emits immediately the last resolved value. I need it to call `libraryCall` again in such cases.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with `shareReplay(0)`, although I've set it's buffer to `0` hoping that nothing ever gets buffered (that is, I need the "share" part, not the "replay" part of `shareReplay`).

How can I amend (or rewrite) it?

Comment: Just after posting the question (after writing that sentence about the "share" part, not the "replay" part), I've learned about the `share()` operator, which solved it all. I'm feeling dumb now, and thinking about deleting the question. But I'm not sure if this question can help anyone out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But... after resolving once, any new subscription emits immediately the last resolved value

This happens possibly because of how the `ReplaySubject` handles the case when the [`bufferSize` argument is `0`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/288397e4066cde6aa4741830659c4ec456380e98/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L55):

```js
/* ... */

this.bufferSize = Math.max(1, bufferSize);

/* ... */
```

So, although you're passing `0` as `bufferSize`, it's going to set `bufferSize` to `1`, which should explain why when a new subscriber registers, it will get the buffered value, instead of invoking the library function again.

I think a quick way to solve it would be:

```js
defer(() => libraryCall()).pipe(
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000))),
  shareReplay({
    bufferSize: 1,
    refCount: true,
  }),
  first(),
);
```

By using the `refCount: true` option, it ensures that when there are no more active subscribers, it will re-subscribe to the source observable, thus recalling the function, when a new subscriber will register.

I think it would help to see what happens in the source code.

When the **entire stream** [is subscribed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/shareReplay.ts#L157):

```js
if (!subject) {
  // subscribed for the first time

  subject = new ReplaySubject<T>(bufferSize, windowTime, scheduler);

  // adding the new subscriber to the `ReplaySubject`'s subscribers list
  // (the `ReplaySubject` extends `Subject`, so this is why it also has a list of subscribers)
  innerSub = subject.subscribe(subscriber);

  // subscribing to the source - this will cause the library function to be called
  subscription = source.subscribe({
    next(value) { subject!.next(value); },
    error(err) {
      const dest = subject;
      subscription = undefined;
      subject = undefined;
      dest!.error(err);
    },
    complete() {
      subscription = undefined;
      subject!.complete();
    },
  });

  // The following condition is needed because source can complete synchronously
  // upon subscription. When that happens `subscription` is first set to `undefined`
  // and right after is set to the "closed subscription" returned by `subscribe`
  if (subscription.closed) {
    subscription = undefined;
  }
} else {
  // subscribed for the second, third etc... time

  // when other subscribers register, they will be added to the `ReplaySubject`'s subscribers list
  // so that every time the source emits, each subscriber will get the same value
  innerSub = subject.subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

By using `first()`, after a subscriber receives a value, a `complete` event will take place, meaning that the subscriber will be removed from the subject's subscribers list.

As far as the `shareReplay` operator is concerned, this is what happens when a [subscriber is removed from the list](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/shareReplay.ts#L185-L193)(due to a `complete`/`error` notification):

```js
subscriber.add(() => {
  refCount--;
  innerSub.unsubscribe();
  if (useRefCount && refCount === 0 && subscription) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    subscription = undefined;
    subject = undefined;
  }
});
```

As you can see, due to `refCount === 0`(no more subscribers in the list) and `useRefCount`(`refCount: true`), you should now get the expected results. If the `if block` is reached, `subject` will become `undefined`, which means that when a new subscriber subscribes to the stream, it will reach the `if (!subject) { ... }` block, so the source will be re-subscribed.

Furthermore, I'd say this requirement will also be fulfilled:

> if every pending client unsubscribes, then the retry loop should be aborted.

---

On a side note, since you don't need the *replay* part, I think you could replace `shareReplay()` with `share()`. (*EDIT: I noticed the comment too late*).